# Iterating insert data from list with selenium using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've got the next site:
[the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp1Jr.jpg)

and I use the next script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

chromedriver = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('http://www.thesite.com')

Contract = browser.find_element_by_id("txtCodContract")
Contract.send_keys("1169650")
browser.find_element_by_name("btnSubmit").click()
time.sleep(5)
```

after this, appears the next site:

[site2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQkxu.jpg)

and I use the next script to return to the initial site:

```
browser.find_element_by_name("btnReturn").click()
```

There's any way to introduce the contract number from a list like this:

```
my_list = ['1169650','2174000','1117870','1223341']
```

and introduce the next one after click the return button? I don't know if it's possible introduce the data from the variable "list" into "send_keys(*value)"
thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use indexing like my_list[0] or my_list[1]

Answer (score 0):

Introduce your list after you click on the button here

```
Contract = browser.find_element_by_id("txtCodContract")
```

something like this

```
my_list = ['1169650','2174000','1117870','1223341']
Contract = browser.find_element_by_id("txtCodContract")
for i in my_list:
     Contract.send_keys(my_list[i])
     browser.find_element_by_name("btnSubmit").click()
     time.sleep(5)
     browser.find_element_by_name("btnReturn").click()
```